# Make Wordpress use the page instead of category

Tags: php, wordpress

I did a great amount of research and came across some solutions like this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106042/force-wordpress-to-show-pages-instead-of-category

But still it isn't *exactly* what I'm looking for. First of all let me explain the problem.

I made a page /blog/ and a category 'blog' both make use of the permalink /blog/, disabled the /category/ permalink so the SEO will be correct.

The solutions I came across didn't match the following requirements:

- Not using 301 redirects
- Disable the /category/ use within Wordpress.
- Also make it possible to only replace category when a page id uses the same slug.

I simply like to tell Wordpress to display the page instead of the category.

**Why don't you just edit the category template?**

Because the page I created uses Visual Composer (Post Masonry Grid) so I can't simple move the design.

**Why don't you just use redirects?**

I would like to but the permalink of the blog is the same as the page (SEO purpose.)

Comment: your want to change the url from category to page? like www.example.com/category to www.example.com/page

Comment: No not really. I want /blog/ to show a page named blog (which slug 'blog'). and use the native category functions of Wordpress. But the category overrides the page slug.

Comment: well i have tested. your need to change the permalink setting add custom permalinks like /%category%/%postname% this will work

Comment: Already did this. This make the url the same as the category. But the category will be displayed. not the page with the same url.

Comment: are you sure both category and page slug is same. well it is working for me. your category url will be example.com/category/blog and page url is example.com/blog. and i don't found any 404

Comment: I **want** to have the same url. That why i would like to display the page instead of the category.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88370/discussion-between-ghulam-ali-and-arno-tenkink).

Comment: In your category template you can get your page with [`get_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) then get the content of it.

Comment: @vard I indeed get the content but the breadcrumbs (Yoast SEO) and visual composer didn't liked this option. Really would like if Wordpress treaded the url als a page instead of a category/archive 'template'.

Comment: Wouldn't be better then to change the slug of your category to a different one, and use the visual composer to display the post of your category?

Comment: @vard Well, Technically that would be correct but because we want to remain a clean structure for Google. It's not really the best option :-/ If I can't find any other solution this would be it.

Comment: I think It'll be hard to work around in an other way - Wordpress consider that your archive page is an archive template - this is set by the post type definition. Though for Google you probably can set some 301 to redirect your archive page slug to the page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know it's a few years later with no solution, but I had the exact same problem you described on one site that was working in other sites. So I did some research on what was different and to help others should they run into the same issue.

**Background**

- example.com is the domain
- I have a WP page called "foobar" with content
- I have a WP post category called "foobar"
- I have a WP post entitled "fun things to do with foobars", and the category is set to "foobar"

**Expectations**

- When I go to `example.com/foobar`, I want to see the page about foobars, not a WP category page that shows all blog posts with that category.
- When I go to the blog post about fun things, the URL is `example.com/foobar/fun-things-to-do-with-foobars/`

**Setup**

Here's my setup (it does not require any additional plugins or code edits)
A couple of installed plugins are WP Rocket and Yoast on which I'll focus in this thread.

1. WP Dashboard->Settings->Permalinks
2. Select "Custom Structure" and enter `/%category%/%postname%/` in the field
3. On the same page, change "Category base" to a single dot. "." (no quotes, just a single dot/period/full stop

I have Yoast installed, which I had set up to override the permalink settings, but I believe this messed up my task at hand.

4. WP Dashboard->SEO->Advanced->Permalinks(tab)
5. "Change URLs->Strip the category base..." = `Keep`
6. Then you need to clear  the cache. I use WP Rocket for caching, so I flushed the cache and everything now works the way it should.

**Edit**: make sure you save your changes after steps 3 and 5

Comment: I just needed to have the word `category` stripped from the URL.

> On the same page, change "Category base" to a single dot. "." (no quotes, just a single dot/period/full stop

That did the trick for me! Using Salient Theme (VC) and Yoast SEO.

Comment: Step 4 and 5 for me were a bit different using Yoast. I had to update the "Remove the categories prefix" setting to "Keep" in Yoast SEO >> Search Appearance>> Taxonomies

Comment: For this worked for top-level categories only. Once I hit a subcategory, things go sideways.  I am  not able to get to a subcategory, instead i am sent to a post with a similar slug value as my category.

So, for me, i have a page and category with matching slug. That category has a subcategory and i have not made the page yet.  I can't get to the category in this scenario, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old but question is still important.

I will use blog example.
This method is code free, WP native solution. One caveat is that you cannot translate "blog" slug, so this method is only for one language if you don't need to have different words/slugs for other languages.

1. Create page with slug "blog". Or whatever you like. **It must match word you put in next step as base: blog = blog it this example**.
2. Set permalink structure in settings to: `/blog/%category/%postname%/` (/ trailing slash on the end is your preference)
3. Use SEO plugin like Yoast or Seopress Pro (or any other
   method) to remove /category from URL.
4. Go to Settings -> Reading -> "Your homepage displays" section -> "A static page (select below)"
5. Set your static page for Homepage
6. Here is the magic: **set Posts page to your "Blog" page.**
7. Flush permalinks by visiting and saving settings on Permalink page (without any change).

Then you will get proper URL: `/blog/yourcategory/single-post-title/`
Breadcrumbs will work, all categories will be hierarchical, and `/blog` **will work as page instead of category**.

Most importantly, when you go to your category page you will get `/blog/yourcategory` URL and it will work as archive page. When you visit single post, then also you get URL `/blog/yourcategory/single-post-title/`

Breadcrumbs from Yoast should work. I use Seopress Pro and breadcrumbs works like a charm (you have to go to breadcrumbs setting page and select categories for posts and posts for categories and tags if you need them).

If you do it without including `/blog` in your permalink setting it will still work, you will get page instead of category with proper url for categories, but single post will be `/yourcategory/single-post-title`.