# Replacing Wordpress Category with Static Page?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm rehashing a Wordpress question from 4 years ago that had an approved answer, but that solution no longer works in the current version of Wordpress.  The original question: [Make Wordpress use the page instead of category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310453/make-wordpress-use-the-page-instead-of-category)

**Background (copied from originally approved answer):**

example.com is the domain

I have a WP page called "foobar" with content

I have a WP post category called "foobar"

I have a WP post entitled "fun things to do with foobars", and the category is set to "foobar"

**Expectations**

When I go to example.com/foobar, I want to see the page about foobars, not a WP category page that shows all blog posts with that category.

When I go to the blog post about fun things, the URL is example.com/foobar/fun-things-to-do-with-foobars/

**The solution at the time**

There appeared to be a work-around with a custom permalink structure and using "." (no quotes) as the category base. That solution does not work with the current version of Wordpress.

There were also a couple of answers that suggested various plugins.  I'm not overtly opposed to that route, but the suggested plugins at the time seem to have been affected by the same update that negated the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

To load page with the same slug as of category name you could use following code snippet that replace category with Page.

```
function wpa_alter_cat_links( $termlink, $term, $taxonomy ){
    if( 'category' != $taxonomy ) return $termlink;
    return str_replace( '/category', '', $termlink );
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpa_alter_cat_links', 10, 3 );
```

Be aware with the code. You should have pages for all your categories otherwise you will get 404 for those categories which have not created pages.

After adding above code into your activated theme's functons.php file please flush the permalink. You can do that with visiting settings -> permalinks -> click save changes

Hope it works for you!